# Trying to get the min date out of set

Tags: sql, sql-server, min, dense-rank

Ok so I have a table that has the following information

```
Company, Employee, Work Date, Job Number
ABC      1234      06/01/15    5555
ABC      1234      06/02/15    5555
ABC      1234      06/03/15    5555
ABC      1234      06/04/15    5555
ABC      1234      06/05/15    5555
ABC      1234      06/06/15    5555
ABC      1234      06/11/15    6666
ABC      1234      06/12/15    6666
ABC      1234      06/13/15    6666
ABC      1234      06/14/15    6666
ABC      1234      06/15/15    6666
ABC      1234      06/16/15    6666
```

The record I want is

```
ABC      1234      06/11/15    6666
```

My first step is to get the most recent work date using this query

```
SELECT TCH.Company_Code, TCH.Employee_Code, CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE) AS Work_Date, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TCH.Employee_Code ORDER BY CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE) DESC) AS DateRank
    FROM PR_TIME_CARD_HISTORY_MC TCH WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE TCH.Company_Code <> 'XYZ' 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(TCH.Employee_Code)) = '22164'
```

The second step is to connect it back to the original table to get the job but I cannot seem to get the set of records for the job to get the min date.

```
SELECT TCH.Company_Code, TCH.Employee_Code, TCH.Job_Number, CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE) AS Work_Date, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TCH.Job_Number ORDER BY CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE) ASC) AS JobRank
    FROM PR_TIME_CARD_HISTORY_MC TCH WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE TCH.Company_Code <> 'XYZ' 
    AND TCH.Pay_Type = 'R'
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(TCH.Employee_Code)) = '22164'
```

Hope this helps and sure could use some guidence.

Comment: Thus the most recent date that employee worked is 06/16/15 and the job number is 6666.  Now I need to get the first day he worked on Job 6666 which is 6/11/15 in the example above.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that the below query should do the job:

```
SELECT company, employee, work_date,job_number FROM
(
SELECT 
 TCH.Company_Code as company, 
 TCH.Employee_Code as employee,
 TCH.Job_Number as job_number, 
 CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE) AS Work_Date, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TCH.Employee_Code,TCH.Company_Code ORDER BY TCH.Job_Number DESC,CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE) ASC) AS DateRank
    FROM PR_TIME_CARD_HISTORY_MC TCH WITH (NOLOCK) 
) q
WHERE q.DateRank=1
```

Comment: After working with it - it does not work.  Darn I was hopeful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

To get the lowest date for the highest `Job_Number` you need to apply both to the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
    SELECT TCH.Company_Code, TCH.Employee_Code, TCH.Job_Number,
       CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE) AS Work_Date, 
       ROW_NUMBER() -- latest row gets 1
       OVER (PARTITION BY TCH.Employee_Code 
             ORDER BY TCH.Job_Number DESC, CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE)) AS DateRank
    FROM PR_TIME_CARD_HISTORY_MC TCH WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE TCH.Company_Code <> 'XYZ' 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(TCH.Employee_Code)) = '1234'
 ) AS dt
WHERE DateRank = 1
```

But if the job numbers are not increasing you need a different logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
    SELECT TCH.Company_Code, TCH.Employee_Code, TCH.Job_Number,
       CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE) AS Work_Date, 
       ROW_NUMBER() -- latest row gets 1
       OVER (PARTITION BY TCH.Employee_Code 
             ORDER BY CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE)) AS DateRank, 

         -- The start date of each job
       MIN(CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE))
       OVER (PARTITION BY TCH.Employee_Code, TCH.Job_Number) AS FirstWorkDate
    FROM PR_TIME_CARD_HISTORY_MC TCH WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE TCH.Company_Code <> 'XYZ' 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(TCH.Employee_Code)) = '1234'
 ) AS dt
WHERE DateRank = 1
```

Comment: What I need is the most recent job and the first day worked on that most recent job.  I think this will give me the most recent job but how do I get the set for records for that job and then get the first date on that job?

Comment: @stylusnix: Is the `Job_Number` always increasing over time? Then simply change to  `ORDER BY Job_Number DESC CAST(TCH.Work_Date AS DATE)`. Otherwise it's more complicated, what's your exact SQL Server release?

Comment: An employee can work on many jobs - usually they go on then off and to another - every once in a while they may work two jobs on one day but that is very rare.   SQL VERSION - 2012

Answer (score 0):

Try this using nested queries in the where clause:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f141c/10)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeCard
(
  Company VARCHAR(10),
  Employee INT,
  WorkDate Date,
  JobNumber Int
)

INSERT INTO TimeCard
VALUES
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/01/15', 5555),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/02/15', 5555),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/03/15', 5555),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/04/15', 5555),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/05/15', 5555),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/06/15', 5555),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/11/15', 6666),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/12/15', 6666),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/13/15', 6666),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/14/15', 6666),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/15/15', 6666),
  ('ABC', 1234, '06/16/15', 6666)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TC.Company, TC.Employee, MIN(TC.WorkDate) AS WorkDate, TC.JobNumber
FROM TimeCard TC
WHERE   TC.Company <> 'XYZ' AND
        TC.Employee = 1234 AND
        TC.JobNumber =
        (    
            -- Get Max JobNumber for the Max Workdate 
            SELECT MAX(JobNumber) 
            FROM TimeCard TC3
            WHERE TC3.WorkDate = 
                -- Get Max WorkDate of Employee
                (
                    SELECT MAX(WorkDate) 
                    FROM TimeCard TC2 
                    WHERE TC2.Employee = TC.Employee
                )
            GROUP BY TC3.Employee
        )
GROUP BY TC.Company, TC.Employee, TC.JobNumber
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f141c/10/0)**:

```
| Company | Employee |   WorkDate | JobNumber |
|---------|----------|------------|-----------|
|     ABC |     1234 | 2015-06-11 |      6666 |
```